# Retrieving String array value in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am doing ajax call from a jsp page that will go to the servlet. The servlet is returing one String array. That I want to use in ajax response data but each time I am getting true not the string array. How can I get string array in response text.

```
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
url="./MacroOperations?copyRoleId="+copyRoleId;
xmlDoc.open("POST",url, false);

xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlDoc.send(null);
    var status=0;
    if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlDoc.status == 200) {
            status=xmlDoc.responseText;
           alert(status);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you check the output of your file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just return the String value in your servlet.